# Why does fasterize gives different output for multipolygons with and without internally resolved boundaries?

Tags: r, rasterization, union, sf, combine

I was thrilled to be clued into the package `fasterize`, which speeds up the rasterization process in R *tremendously*.

However, I cannot figure out why the `fasterize()` function outputs two different rasters when generated from a multipolygon with internally resolved boundaries and a multipolygon with*out* internally resolved boundaries. I have tried specifying `fun = "any"` in the fasterize parameters, as well as `fun = "sum"`. The former should (I believe) take any area where there's a polygon; the latter should take the sum of any overlapping polygons. In both cases, the coverage should be the same. However, the raster from the multipolygon generated from `st_combine()` drops overlapping areas whereas the raster from the multipolygon generated from `st_union()` keeps any/all areas.

Am I missing something? Why are there holes in the middle plot (rasterized from `st_combine()`?? There's reproducible code below the plot, with [sample shapefile here](https://github.com/CaitLittlef/random) (of Yellowstone and Grand Teton NPs -- provided as separate shapefile components and as zipped folder).

[image: comparison plots]

```
# Read in shapefile.
YNPGT <- st_read("YNPGT.shp")
bbox <- st_bbox(YNPGT) # Keep bounding box for plotting b/c global extent
# Rasterize. "Sum" so any spot with poly is retained (e.g., not just 'first' poly).
YNPGT.r <- YNPGT %>% fasterize(raster = ref.ras, fun = "sum")

# Combine that to flatten all polygons into one -- resolves internal boundaries
combo <- st_combine(YNPGT)
# Rasterize 
combo <- st_sf(combo) # combine outputs sfc; need sf for fasterize.
combo.r <- combo %>% fasterize(raster = ref.ras, fun = "sum")

# Union that to flatten all polygons into one -- drops internal boundaries.
union <- st_union(YNPGT)
# Rasterize 
union <- st_sf(union) # combine outputs sfc; need sf for fasterize.
union.r <- union %>% fasterize(raster = ref.ras, fun = "sum")


par(mfrow=c(2,3))
plot(st_geometry(YNPGT),
     xlim=c(bbox[1], bbox[3]), ylim=c(bbox[2], bbox[4]),
     col = c("green", "pink"))
title("YNP-GT orig")
plot(st_geometry(combo),
     xlim=c(bbox[1], bbox[3]), ylim=c(bbox[2], bbox[4]),
     col = c("green", "pink"))
title("YNP-GT  st_combine")
plot(st_geometry(union),
     xlim=c(bbox[1], bbox[3]), ylim=c(bbox[2], bbox[4]),
     col = c("green", "pink"))
title("YNP-GT  st_union")
plot(YNPGT.r,
     xlim=c(bbox[1], bbox[3]), ylim=c(bbox[2], bbox[4]),
     col = c("green", "pink"))
title("YNP-GT raster from orig")
plot(combo.r,
     xlim=c(bbox[1], bbox[3]), ylim=c(bbox[2], bbox[4]),
     col = c("green", "pink"))
title("YNP-GT raster from st_combine")
plot(union.r,
     xlim=c(bbox[1], bbox[3]), ylim=c(bbox[2], bbox[4]),
     col = c("green", "pink"))
title("YNP-GT raster from st_union")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of things going on here, I think. First, `fasterize` doesn't have `...` enabled so you can't pass `na.rm = TRUE` through your summarising function, and all of those default to FALSE.

The other issue is that as the documentation warns, the output of `st_combine()` is often not valid under the simple features spec so may perform unexpectedly. If you run `combo` through `lwgeom::st_make_valid() %>% st_collection_extract(., 'POLYGON')`, you'll see the combination resolves to a valid sfc_MULTIPOLYGON but treats some overlapping polygons from `YNPGT[2, ]` as holes, because they're fully contained by `YNPGT[1, ]`.

I don't think the results of `st_combine()` with polygons are generally safe for rasterizing. I get the sense that its most useful for point and line geometries.

Comment: Thanks for these thoughts -- very helpful. I'll be cautious when using st_combine() in the future.